# Creating nodes at polyline vertices of gis shape file

Tags: mesa-abm

I am new to mesa but have created an ABM (Agent-Based-Model) previously using netlogo. I am aware that there is a Gis extension for mesa ABM platform called geo-mesa. What I am interested in is, if there is a road network (polyline) shapefile if its possible to allow the agents to be moved on these roads. 
(In Netlogo you do this by creating a node (a type of agent) at the vertices of the polyline allowing agents to traverse the road network by jumping from node to node.) Is something similar possible in mesa/geo mesa. Also, are there any other Models created using mesa apart from the tutorials in mesa and geo-mesa website, Geoschelling model.
Thanks in advance for any helpful comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Continuous Space grid and set your turtles in motion with the get_heading() function. Some (little) reference is presented on https://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/master/apis/space.html#space.ContinuousSpace. Besides the project page, the project github page (https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa) is the best source for how to use mesa. Yet, it is still a module to get people using it and sharing their experience. Good luck on you modelling!